# PDF header signature not found, iText

Tags: pdf, itext

Hi I am trying to read a PDF file which is being uploaded by the servlet.

Here is the code

```
//out = byte array
out = readInItem(item);
fileToUpload = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

Map<String, AcroFields.Item> pdfBoxNames = new HashMap<String, AcroFields.Item>();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileToUpload);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);
AcroFields acroFields = stamper.getAcroFields();
pdfBoxNames = acroFields.getFields();
```

My pdf starts like this %PDF-1.6

Error message is 
java.io.IOException: PDF header signature not found.

Comment: I found the solution. PDFReader takes only the inputstream that you get from item.openstream(); if you convert that into something like ByteArrayInputStream it will start throwing exceptions. So only give the inputstream that you get from when you upload the file.

Comment: You could of course also construct the PdfReader object with the byte array containing the PDF bytes. You don't need to create the ByteArrayInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same exception! Make sure you have included the `TableHeader` and a writer `PageEvent` set for that. I just added them up and this exception was gone! Hope it helps you

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
TableHeader includeHeader = new TableHeader();
writer.setPageEvent(includeHeader);
```