# Adding page to existing PDF com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to add a page to an already created PDF using iText 1.02b using Java 1.5.  When I add the new page to the existing PDF I get the exception that I included.  Here is the code in the method we are having the issue.

```
public static File addSignaturePageToPDF(String fileName, InputStream fileInputStream, SignatureTemplateInfo signaturePageInfo, HttpServletRequest argRequest) throws Exception {

int splitIdx = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        File signedFile = File.createTempFile(fileName.substring(0,splitIdx), fileName.substring(splitIdx));
        SignatureModel signatureModel = SignatureHelper.getSignatureModel(signaturePageInfo.getCaseHeaders(), signaturePageInfo.getEventSubTp(), signaturePageInfo.getSignatureId(), argRequest);

        byte[] signaturePdfAsBytes = SignatureHelper.createSignature(signatureModel, argRequest);
        byte[] mainPdfAsBytes = getByteArrayFromInputStream(fileInputStream);
    PdfReader mainPdfReader = new PdfReader(mainPdfAsBytes);  << Exception here
    PdfReader signaturePdfReader = new PdfReader(signaturePdfAsBytes);
```

Exception:

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.checkPdfHeader(PRTokeniser.java:205)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:496)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:189)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:178)
    at icis.common.util.ConvertDocument.addSignaturePageToPDF(ConvertDocument.java:96)
    at icis.cr.common.file.ViewFileAction.executeProcess(ViewFileAction.java:71)
    at icis.common.action.BaseICISAction.execute(BaseICISAction.java:134)
    at icis.cr.common.BaseCRAction.execute(BaseCRAction.java:41)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Consider storing the contents of signaturePdfAsBytes and mainPdfAsBytes into some topiary files and inspect them.

Comment: Wow  - normally I am not the one pointing out that you are using a mighty old version of iText - but nearly 10 years is even too old for me ;-) 1. Did you consider using a bit newer version? Maybe that problem was fixed a long time ago. 2. To detect whether you have a problem  insert the following line before your exception: System.out.println(new String(mainPdfAsBytes)); and check whether it starts with 'PDF-1.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception tells you that the first bytes obtained from your `fileInputStream` aren't equal to `'%'`, `'P'`, `'D'`, `'F'`, `'-'`, `'1'`, `'.'`.

Maybe the file you're trying to inspect is empty, maybe the `InputStream` can't be read correctly,...

Many people before you have encountered and fixed the same problem:

- [How to solve pdf header signature not found error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655027/how-to-solve-pdf-header-signature-not-found-error)
- [PDF header signature not found, iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518254/pdf-header-signature-not-found-itext)
- [com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831418/com-itextpdf-text-exceptions-invalidpdfexception-pdf-header-signature-not-found)
- [iTextSharp exception: PDF header signature not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621936/itextsharp-exception-pdf-header-signature-not-found)
- [Error PDF header signature not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169085/error-pdf-header-signature-not-found)
- [itextsharp multipage pdf form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142750/itextsharp-multipage-pdf-form)
- ...

You should debug your code, by saving `mainPdfAsBytes` to a file and by examining that file. Is it really a PDF file? iText tells you it doesn't start with `%PDF-1.`.

Comment: Thanks Bruno!  It is great to meet you virtually :)

Comment: Make sure the file path is, in fact, a PDF file instead of something else. I had a "File list" from a given directory and the filter was missing the file.getName().endsWith(".pdf").